# Where to install SSL certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate, subdomain

I have 3 apps:

1. WebApi at `api.something.com`
2. SPA at `app.something.com`
3. MVC at `www.something.com`

Both SPA and MVC makes ajax calls to WebApi which needs to be encrypted in transit.

So, my question is where should SSL certificate be installed? On all 3 domains or only on `api.something.com` ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should install a wildcard DNS and SSL. There is a screencast about this here that should help you out: 
http://scottcate.com/technology/microsoft-azure-websites-full-support-for-wildcard-dns-and-ssl/

Comment: Are you suggesting that I would have to install SSL on all sub-domains?

Comment: That is what wildcard certificates are for :)